# How can I change the path of component generation to current path in angular-cli?

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I'm following an angular 2 course where the instructor navigates into the specific path where he wants to generate a component and then runs the following command:

```
ng generate component component-name
```

After he runs it, the tool generates the files inside the current directory, but when I try the same, the tool ends up generating the files at the app root folder.

In other words, if I do this:

```
app\my-component> ng generate component component-name
```

I expect the command to generate files here:

```
app\my-component\component-name\
  component-name.component.html
  component-name.component.ts
  ...
```

But instead is doing it here:

```
app\component-name\
  component-name.component.html
  component-name.component.ts
  ...
```

How can I tell ng-cli to use current path?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

```
ng g c 'path/to/component/componentName'
```

You should never have to leave your root directory when working with angular cli. If you wanted all your components to go into a subdirectory called my-component you would just do `ng g c my-component/componentName`

Note that g and c are valid shortforms for `generate` and `component` respectively.

Comment: Thanks for the response. But I'm asking this precisely because the course instructor works with it like that. I have a coworker that also uses it like that... just navigating to the path where you want to generate your components.

Comment: The angular cli is under constant development. This may be a feature that has been deprecated. The current recommendation as per the documentation on their GItHub is to pass in the path name as I've demonstrated.

Comment: Yes, I understand that this is in active development right now, so I expect to see some inconsistencies like these along the way... It might have been deprecated... but what is funny is that my coworker has a slight bigger angular-cli version. He is using 1.0.0-beta.26. I'm using 1.0.0-beta.25.5

Answer (score 3):

Suppose you have structure `src/app` and you wanna create a component `header` living at `src/app/components/` you can run `ng g c components/header`, which will generate files at `src/app/components/header` folder, like `src/app/components/header/header.component.ts` `src/app/components/header/header.component.html` etc.

Answer (score 3):

Well, after some googling and reading the other answers, it will be helpful to have some explanations here.
To generate a component in your project:

```
cd  path/your-project
```

In the console (node-prompt or your IDE console) type:

```
ng generate component components/your-new-component-name
```

If you want to abbreviate:

```
ng g c components/your-new-component-name
```

You can create other angular components like:
ng g directive 
ng g module
...

Source and more info: [Angular Official Documentation](https://angular.io/cli/generate)

You should avoid: 
'route-to-your-project': this will concatenate routes when you execute: ng g c 'route-to-your-project' and the console will show you an error because could not find the correct place to generate.

Example:

```
 ng g c components/alerts/test3

CREATE src/app/components/alerts/test3/test3.component.html (20 bytes)
CREATE src/app/components/alerts/test3/test3.component.spec.ts (621 bytes)
CREATE src/app/components/alerts/test3/test3.component.ts (266 bytes)
CREATE src/app/components/alerts/test3/test3.component.scss (0 bytes)
UPDATE src/app/components/alerts/alerts.module.ts (5046 bytes)
```

I hope it will be helpful for you

Answer (score 0):

I ran into something similar to this when following Max Schwartzmuller's Udemy course.  I was trying to generate components in a subfolder parallel to app.  The cli will create anything called that way directly under app.

```
c:\ng2\aufbs\src\mycomponents>ng g c my-test
installing component
  create src\app\my-test\my-test.component.css
  create src\app\my-test\my-test.component.html
  create src\app\my-test\my-test.component.spec.ts
  create src\app\my-test\my-test.component.ts
```

moving /mycomponents under app everything worked as expected.

Answer (score 0):

set the path from app folder, so you dont need use `ng g c 'C:\someFolder\your-project\src\app\some-folder\other-folder\your-component'`.
just use `ng g c '.\pages\shered\reset-password'`